# Trying to run a python django website but Mod_wsgi is not working

Tags: python, django, apache, apache2, mod-wsgi

I am trying to run a pyhton django project using apache2 and mod_wsgi on linux.

It doesn't seem to be running any of the python code. When I enter the website's url (mysite.com on my server) in my browser the page loads the template file it is supposed to, however, any python appears as regular text and the static files don't load either.

To check if mod_wsgi is enabled I typed a2enmod in the terminal and it says that Module wsgi already enabled. Also, this was an existing project that worked fine on the development server.

I was following the tutorial on https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/
and so I added the code below to the httpd.conf file when starting the project.

```
<IfModule wsgi_module>
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/mysite/mysite/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mysite

Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/signup/static/signup

<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite>
<Files wsgi.py>
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
</Files>
</Directory>

<Directory /var/www/mysite/mysite/template>
DirectoryIndex integrate.html
Options Indexes FollowSymLinks

</Directory>


WSGIDaemonProcess mysite.com python-path=/var/www/mysite:/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
WSGIProcessGroup mysite.com
</IfModule>
```

Comment: What does your httpd.conf file contain? Are you using virtualenv?

Comment: did you edit to the python.conf in the httpd to create a alias to your project??

Comment: You're at least going to have to show your apache configuration.

Comment: And what URLs are you going to when you see raw Python?

Comment: I see the raw python when I go to mysite.com

Comment: Why do you have the Directory block for '/var/www/mysite/mysite/template'?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that is wrong is that:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/signup/static/signup
```

should be:

```
Alias /static /var/www/mysite/signup/static/signup
```

or:

```
Alias /static/ /var/www/mysite/signup/static/signup/
```

For a sub URL, the use of trailing slash must be balanced. That is, appear on both or not on both.

You are also missing a Directory block for the directory '/var/www/mysite/signup/static' to tell Apache it can access files in that directory.

What I don't understand is why though you have it mapping to a 'signup' subdirectory. Why wouldn't it be mapping to just the 'static' directory? You possibly have something wonky there as well.

Finally, if you are seeing Python source code, then sounds a bit like you have put your Django site under DocumentRoot, which is totally wrong, and then the above isn't being used. But then it isn't totally obvious what the problem is as you haven't explained it very well. What you have done not actually following the Django documentation doesn't help. I would suggest you go read the documentation again.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using WSGIDaemonProcess and WSGIProcessGroup (which I always put first) remove 
`WSGIPythonPath /var/www/mysite`

I also don't have `<IfModule wsgi_module>`or `DirectoryIndex`(which should be covered by your URLConf)

Are you using templates? not sure why you would see raw python.

Comment: Things like {% csrf_token %} in my template show up when I open it. Don't know why though